# SQL CASE WHEN Recurring expression in case clause

Tags: sql, db2

my query:

```
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN 
DAYS(DATE(
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),5,4)  CONCAT '-'  CONCAT
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),9,2)  CONCAT '-01') - 1 DAY + 1 MONTH)
- DAYS(HUB_ARRIVAL_DT) < 31 THEN ' 030'
WHEN 
DAYS(DATE(
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),5,4)  CONCAT '-'  CONCAT
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),9,2)  CONCAT '-01') - 1 DAY + 1 MONTH)
- DAYS(HUB_ARRIVAL_DT) < 61 THEN ' 060'
WHEN 
DAYS(DATE(
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),5,4)  CONCAT '-'  CONCAT
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),9,2)  CONCAT '-01') - 1 DAY + 1 MONTH)
- DAYS(HUB_ARRIVAL_DT) < 91 THEN ' 090'
WHEN 
DAYS(DATE(
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),5,4)  CONCAT '-'  CONCAT
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),9,2)  CONCAT '-01') - 1 DAY + 1 MONTH)
- DAYS(HUB_ARRIVAL_DT) < 181 THEN ' 180'
ELSE '>180'
END AS AGED
FROM ...
```

you can see the following parts is copied several times

```
DAYS(DATE(
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),5,4)  CONCAT '-'  CONCAT
SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),9,2)  CONCAT '-01') - 1 DAY + 1 MONTH)
- DAYS(HUB_ARRIVAL_DT)
```

Is it possible to have this only once? If so, how? Will this have a performance impact? Thanks! Database is DB2.

Comment: What's the type of column STOCK_MONTH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea about DB2, but I would try this:

```
select
  CASE 
  WHEN 
  computed_col < 31 THEN ' 030'
  ...
  END AS AGED
from
(
  select DAYS(DATE(
  SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),5,4)  CONCAT '-'  CONCAT
  SUBSTR(DIGITS(STOCK_MONTH),9,2)  CONCAT '-01') - 1 DAY + 1 MONTH)
  - DAYS(HUB_ARRIVAL_DT) as computed_col
  from...
) as x
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try stored functions. Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION daysdiff (
    "start" INT, 
    "end" DATE
) RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  RETURN DAYS(DATE(
              SUBSTR(DIGITS(daysdiff."start"),5,4)  CONCAT '-'  CONCAT
              SUBSTR(DIGITS(daysdiff."start"),9,2)  CONCAT '-01') - 1 DAY + 1 MONTH)
         - DAYS(daysdiff."end")

CREATE FUNCTION monthly (
   "days" INT
) RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  RETURN CEILING(monthly."days" / 30) * 30

CREATE FUNCTION daystr ("days" INT, "max" INT)
  RETURNS char(4)
  DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  RETURN
    CASE WHEN daystr."days" <= daystr."max" THEN
        CHAR(DECIMAL(daystr."days", INT(LOG10(daystr."max"))+1, 0))
    ELSE '>' CONCAT CHAR(DECIMAL(daystr."max", INT(LOG10(daystr."max"))+1, 0))
    END

CREATE FUNCTION monthlydiffstr (
    "start" INT, 
    "end" DATE
) RETURNS INT
  RETURN daystr(monthly(daysdiff(monthlydiffstr."start", monthlydiffstr."end")), 180)
```

The above was not tested on DB2; your mileage and syntax may vary. Feel free to rename the functions (which are admittedly bad) and break down the tasks into whatever functions you see fit. `daysdiff` could probably be improved, depending on the type of `STOCK_MONTH`.